# How to get getUserMedia fullscreen on different devices in html video element with React?

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, getusermedia, window-resize

For an AR project I am trying to get a full screen video stream from a device's cameras via getUserMedia. Unfortunately, this only partially works, even after trying several (possible) solutions I found online.

It has now become clear to me that I need the autoPlay, playsInline and muted in video tag to ensure that the video can be seen in iOS. It has not yet been possible to get the video for both andriod and iOs and desktop fullscreen.

To display the camera feed, I use the following React component:

```
export const TestGame = () => {
    const { screenWidth, screenHeight } = useWindowResize()
    const videoRef = useRef(null)
    const canvasRef = useRef(null)

    const getVideo = async (screenHeight, screenWidth) => {
        try {
            let video = videoRef.current
            let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: {
                        // width: {ideal: screenWidth },
                        // height: {ideal: screenHeight },
                        video: true,
                        audio: false,
                        facingMode: 'user',
                    }
                })
            video.srcObject = stream
            video.play()
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getVideo(screenHeight, screenWidth)
    }, [videoRef,screenHeight, screenWidth])

    return (
        <div className='game-page-container'>
            <canvas 
                id='game-container'
                className='game-container'
                ref={canvasRef}
            />  
            <div className='video-container'>
                <video
                    id='video-container'
                    className='video-source'
                    ref={videoRef}
                    autoPlay
                    playsInline
                    muted
                /> 
            </div>
        </div> 
    )
}
```

I also tried to make use of the screen dimensions. For this I made a custom hook, which also reacts to changes in the screen size. This hook is currently not being used.

```
export function useWindowResize() {
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    screenWidth: window.innerWidth,
    screenHeight: window.innerHeight,
    screenRatio: window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      const isLandscape = window.innerHeight <= window.innerWidth;
      const ratio = isLandscape ? 
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight: 
        window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth 

        setWindowSize({
          screenWidth: window.innerWidth,
          screenHeight: window.innerHeight,
          screenRatio: ratio
        });
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    handleResize();

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowSize;
}
```

I have tried to use the dimensions of the screen, so that even when rotating a mobile device, the screen is completely filled by the video. However, this will not work yet. In addition, the video on andriod seems zoomed in and off-center. So far it only seems to work well for desktop and laptop.

I hope someone can help me to get it working for all devices.